# Symfony 4 in subdirectory

Tags: apache, symfony, symfony4

I did install Symfony **4** on a subdirectory of my wamp localhost. My project is named "cardMaker".

I've a .htaccess file to redirect towards the public directory (index.php) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule "^$" public/ [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . srcAngular/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

That works. But, when I open `http://localhost/cardMaker/`, I have this:

[image: page could not be found error]

How can I set the base url ?

Comment: So, and what you see opening `http://localhost`? And did you read the [Symfony Documentation about server configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)?

Comment: And its not a good idea to access symfony project using subdirectory. Create a hostname in your hosts file like that `project.dev    127.0.0.1/cardMaker` and use `project.dev` in your browser. As far as I know wamp also have that functionality.

Comment: Is the cardMaker route defined? It would be much easier to help you if you would provide some code and logs also.

Comment: Thank's for your answers.

I've configure a virtualhost for my project, and it's works

Comment: @Sphinx can you post it as an answer as a reference for others having the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here at https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html they say:

```
# If you run your Symfony application on a subpath of your document root, the
# regular expression must be changed accordingly:
# ProxyPassMatch ^/path-to-app/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/project/public/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the symfony app as an alias.  Configure your apache httpd.conf file:

```
Alias /cardMaker "C:/Csi\CsiWorkspace/cardMaker/public"
<Directory "C:/Csi\CsiWorkspace/cardMaker/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule cache/ - [F]
    RewriteBase /symfonytest

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
    RewriteRule ^ ./index.php [L]
  </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Notice the use of **RewriteBase** for the alias **cardMaker**

Answer (score 0):

This config (with php-fpm) currently works for me:

Apache: 2.4

Symfony: 3.4.44

```
<Directory /var/www/example.local>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

Alias /cardMaker /var/www/example.local/cardMaker/public
<Directory /var/www/example.local/cardMaker/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
        RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
        RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

        RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
        RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_alias.c>
            RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</Directory>


ProxyPassMatch ^/cardMaker(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/example.local/cardMaker/public$1
```